# What is the difference between System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture and System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture

Tags: c#, .net

What I can see in documents provided by Microsoft is only that one is static one is not static.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=net-5.0

They looks like having identical function, are they?

Comment: Source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,ff8fd0bdccb4794e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are identical because `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` calls `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture`: [Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,ff8fd0bdccb4794e)